# Shared hosts do not yet support Rails on Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting, shared-hosting

Could someone offer some advice please.

I have a first revision of an application that I developed under rails 3.1 and ruby 1.9.2. It wasn't until I came to deploying the application that I discovered my shared host does not support ruby 1.9.2 (most shared hosting seems to be the same). I tried to deploy my rails 3.1 application anyway, but have encountered many problems, often to do with the deprecated => syntax.

I am now trying to figure out what to do, and am thinking of recreating my application under an earlier version of rails.

What are my options?
What version of rails should I downgrade to, to avoid the problems I have been having?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use RVM to install your own Ruby 1.9.2.  See https://rvm.io/rvm/install/.

Comment: That's the beauty of it.  If you have SSH shell access, you have everything that you need to set it up.  You use RVM for ruby, wget the rubygems tar file and set that up and then gem install everything else after you run rvm 1.9.2 --default to default to your instance of Ruby.  Then log out and back in.

Answer (score 1):

You could give heroku a try. They have a free tier and I believe the Cedar stack supports rails 3.1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, couldn't see a free option with heroku http://www.heroku.com/pricing#0-0. My application is in the early stages of testing and development, so I can't justify a large monthly outlay yet.

Comment: Heroku gives you 750 free hours. This means you get 1 free web dyno per month (although it doesn't say so on that page except at the very bottom -750 free hours). I don't think you even have to enter a credit card to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy to [Heroku](http://heroku.com) or [CloudFoundy](http://cloudfoundry.org). They support ruby-1.9.2.

Comment: thanks, I can't justify the expense with Heroku just yet, i will certainly take a look at CloundFoundry.